# Flexgrid And Grid not working as Responsive in Angular

Tags: css, angular, primeng

As you can see in the picture below the buttons have not equal size and the margin between them so different for all buttons.

I know i can give fixed width to buttons but it would ruined responsive design therefore i dont wanna do that .

When the screen becoming smaller all the buttons overflow others on so seems responsive grid not working as expected.

Also i want  p-selectButton  as i mean the 2 flags button should stick to end of the page.But i couldn't do that with margin-right:0px.

I tried depreceated grid aswell but the page looks same.Thanks in advance.

My page looks like this:
[image: My page looks like]

Aakash Garg work :
[image]

My html :

```
   <div class="p-grid" style="background-color: #2c3e50;">
    <div class="p-col-7">
        <div class="p-grid">
            <div class="p-xl-auto p-lg-1 p-md-3 p-sm-12" style="display: table;">
                <p-button icon="pi pi-home" [label]="'anasayfa' | translate" routerLink="anasayfa" class="box"></p-button>
            </div>

            <div class="p-xl-auto p-lg-1 p-md-3 p-sm-12" style="display: table;">
                <p-button class="box" icon="pi pi-info" [label]="'profil' | translate" routerLink="profil" [style.display]="loggedInUser ? '' : 'none'"></p-button>
            </div>

            <div class="p-xl-auto p-lg-1 p-md-3 p-sm-12" style="display: table;">
                <p-button class="box" icon="pi pi-users" [label]="'calisanlar' | translate" routerLink="calisanlar" [style.display]="loggedInUser ? '' : 'none'"></p-button>
            </div>

            <div class="p-xl-auto p-lg-1 p-md-3 p-sm-12" style="display: table;">
                <p-button class="box" icon="pi pi-sliders-v" [label]="'gorevler' | translate" routerLink="gorevler" [style.display]="loggedInUser ? '' : 'none'"></p-button>
            </div>

            <div class="p-xl-auto p-lg-1 p-md-3 p-sm-12" style="display: table;">
                <p-button class="box" icon="pi pi-id-card" [label]="'musteriler' | translate" routerLink="musteriler" [style.display]="loggedInUser ? '' : 'none'"></p-button>
            </div>

            <div class="p-xl-auto p-lg-1 p-md-3 p-sm-12" style="display: table;">
                <p-button class="box" icon="pi pi-shopping-cart" [label]="'urunler' | translate" routerLink="urunler" [style.display]="loggedInUser ? '' : 'none'"></p-button>
            </div>

            <div class="p-xl-auto p-lg-1 p-md-3 p-sm-12" style="display: table;">
                <p-button class="box" icon="pi pi-briefcase" [label]="'varliklar' | translate" routerLink="finansalvarliklar" [style.display]="loggedInUser ? '' : 'none'"></p-button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="p-col-3"></div>

    <div class="p-col-2" style="padding-top: 1.5em;">
        <p-selectButton [options]="countries" [(ngModel)]="selectedCountry" optionLabel="name" (click)="translateService.use(selectedCountry.name)">
            <ng-template let-item>
                <div style="padding: 0.5em 1em;">
                    <img style="vertical-align: middle; margin-right: 0.5em;" src="assets/{{item.value.flag}}" height="25px" />
                </div>
            </ng-template>
        </p-selectButton>
    </div>

    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

My scss file :

```
:host ::ng-deep .ui-button-text {
    margin-left: 10px;
}

.box {
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 1em;
    padding-bottom: 1em;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use html below :-

```
<div class="p-grid p-justify-between" style="background-color: #2c3e50;">
    <div class="p-col-7">
        <div class="p-grid p-justify-between">
            <div class="p-xl-auto p-lg-1 p-md-3 p-sm-12" style="display: table;">
                <p-button icon="pi pi-home" [label]="'anasayfa' | translate" routerLink="anasayfa" class="box"></p-button>
            </div>

            <div class="p-xl-auto p-lg-1 p-md-3 p-sm-12" style="display: table;">
                <p-button class="box" icon="pi pi-info" [label]="'profil' | translate" routerLink="profil" [style.display]="loggedInUser ? '' : 'none'"></p-button>
            </div>

            <div class="p-xl-auto p-lg-1 p-md-3 p-sm-12" style="display: table;">
                <p-button class="box" icon="pi pi-users" [label]="'calisanlar' | translate" routerLink="calisanlar" [style.display]="loggedInUser ? '' : 'none'"></p-button>
            </div>

            <div class="p-xl-auto p-lg-1 p-md-3 p-sm-12" style="display: table;">
                <p-button class="box" icon="pi pi-sliders-v" [label]="'gorevler' | translate" routerLink="gorevler" [style.display]="loggedInUser ? '' : 'none'"></p-button>
            </div>

            <div class="p-xl-auto p-lg-1 p-md-3 p-sm-12" style="display: table;">
                <p-button class="box" icon="pi pi-id-card" [label]="'musteriler' | translate" routerLink="musteriler" [style.display]="loggedInUser ? '' : 'none'"></p-button>
            </div>

            <div class="p-xl-auto p-lg-1 p-md-3 p-sm-12" style="display: table;">
                <p-button class="box" icon="pi pi-shopping-cart" [label]="'urunler' | translate" routerLink="urunler" [style.display]="loggedInUser ? '' : 'none'"></p-button>
            </div>

            <div class="p-xl-auto p-lg-1 p-md-3 p-sm-12" style="display: table;">
                <p-button class="box" icon="pi pi-briefcase" [label]="'varliklar' | translate" routerLink="finansalvarliklar" [style.display]="loggedInUser ? '' : 'none'"></p-button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="p-col-3"></div>

    <div class="p-col-2" style="padding-top: 1.5em;">
        <p-selectButton [options]="countries" [(ngModel)]="selectedCountry" optionLabel="name" (click)="translateService.use(selectedCountry.name)">
            <ng-template let-item>
                <div style="padding: 0.5em 1em;">
                    <img style="vertical-align: middle; margin-right: 0.5em;" src="assets/{{item.value.flag}}" height="25px" />
                </div>
            </ng-template>
        </p-selectButton>
    </div>

    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried your code The buttons margin looks equal but they showing in vertical way. I wanna show them in horizontal way.Also the buttons size not equal like mine.I added a picture to my post to show that how yours looks like

Comment: Now changed but not all of them 4 in one row 3  inanother one row I updated photo either.

Comment: Now 2*6 = 12 so 6 buttons at same row.Last one and the flags gone beneath them . It's really wreckage. I dunno how to lift it :D

Comment: ofcourse not i just used for having advantage of flex grid but i cant

Comment: The margin between buttons different.I made it that with giving style "display: table;" to each divs now they have same margin.It just left buttons size equality.I updated my post

Comment: provide stackblitz please?

Comment: attach screenshot above?

Comment: hey updated code above, remove margin from your css and try the above code.

Comment: https://angular-ivy-ytfzow.stackblitz.io/ I gave fixed width to buttons and also buttons have same margin between them.

Comment: try the solution i gave above? don't have margin in css

Comment: i tried also i updated photo again the result same like before

Comment: i did it https://angular-ivy-ytfzow.stackblitz.io/ . I just removed empty div and set p-col to 10 and with 2 flag buttons all Complements to 12 so working thank you for your great help.